# Android Eclipse incoming vs outgoing SMS: Phone number format?

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a application that captures the in/outgoing SMS on Android devices.

Now since I'm already in the beta release, I noticed on my SQL server that the incoming SMS adress is formatted as an international number, like +32477889977.

However, the outgoing SMS gets formatted like 0477 88 99 77, the way the user stores it on his phone.

My code for outgoing SMS is

```
int addressColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex("address");
String number = cursor.getString(addressColumn);
```

But in the incoming monitor the code is

```
String from = msg[i].getOriginatingAddress();
```

Now the question is, how can I make the incoming SMS to have the same format as the outgoing, so the international number, and not the number stored in the phone?

It is vital for my application that the phone numbers are international, since I target a worldwide application. So local formatting is not an option. I really need to read the number that was sent by the network.

Answer (score 2):

You should use E164 numbers format.
E164 is a standard for phone numbers formatting, it takes into account the locale that you are working on.

Google has their E164 library: [https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/](https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber)

an example of formatting a number in E164 using the library will look something like:

```
    PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
    PhoneNumber phoneNumber;
    try {
        phoneNumber = phoneUtil.parse(phone, locale.getCountry());
    } catch (NumberParseException e) {
        throw new InvalidNumberException(convertErrorType(e.getErrorType()), e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    String formatedMsisdn = phoneUtil.format(phoneNumber, PhoneNumberFormat.E164);
```

When you receive an SMS the number is already e164 formatted so you will get the same number when using the lib, but when you send an SMS you should first format it using a code such as above to get it in E164 format.
The locale you use is typically the locale the device is set to, you can get it by calling:

```
Locale.getDefault()
```

then passing the locale to the E164 library.

Comment: I really love your answer, however, i always get the error:missing metadata: /com/google/i18n/phonenumbers/data/PhoneNumberMetadataProto_BE. As you seem to have worked with the lib before, can you help me out?

Comment: <pre>Locale local = Locale.getDefault();
   
   String swissNumberStr = sms.mNumber;
   PhoneNumber swissNumberProto = null;
   
    PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
    try {
       swissNumberProto = phoneUtil.parse(swissNumberStr, local.getCountry());
    } catch (NumberParseException e) {
      System.err.println("NumberParseException was thrown: " + e.toString());
    }

      
   String testing = phoneUtil.format(swissNumberProto, PhoneNumberFormat.E164);</pre>

Comment: Just tried it with a blank project and it worked... Did you download the jar (libphonenumber-5.4.jar), added it to your classpath and exported it?

Comment: Hi inistel, Yes, i did exactly that. Also tried with the 5.2 and 5.4, none of them seems to work on a BELGIAN number, like 0477 88 99 00

Comment: I guess you are doing something wrong because I just used your code and it worked (although my device's locale is US so I got +1477889900). What do you have in your `locale` variable?

Comment: Hello again and thanks for your patience!! The variable return "BE" when i log it. So i'm guessing it's more a problem with the library itself. You can always try to use "BE" instead of locale.getCountry() to test.

Comment: Try and see what happens when you create locale manually: `new Locale("fr", "BE");` and see if it works

Comment: Hi inistel, still the same error and the same issue with `new Locale("fr", "BE");`

Comment: I don't know what exactly but there is something wrong in your configuration, the file that the error says is missing (**PhoneNumberMetadataProto_BE**) exists in the [source code](https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fjava%2Flibphonenumber%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fi18n%2Fphonenumbers%2Fdata).    You should check you have everything in place.

Comment: I'll just give this library up and will try some other workarounds :-/

Comment: FWIW there is the PhoneNumberUtils.class in the telephony package. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html